# Add new geometry columns in postgres using python

Tags: python, geometry, postgis, postgresql-9.3

I'm new in postgres and postgis, I loaded data from csv file to postgres database but the problem is when I want to add a new geometry column. 
thank you for your help

```
try:
   cursor.execute("""alter table Pluvometre add column geom geometry(point, 4326)
                  using st_setsrid(st_makepoint(X, Y),4326);""")
except:
   print "Error add gemetry column"

my data:
--------
  X                Y               ID  nosico noi  mt8_x             mt8_y            lat  lon
-74.0313470791373 45.3929059093611 1 OBXL1011 33   263196.452317745  5028244.700001    45 -74
-73.9491598482168 45.39888024068   2 OBXL1021 21   269635.2727916759 5028869.415663255 45 -74
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The USING clause cannot be used with ADD COLUMN. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-altertable.html

In your case you need two statements: a ALTER TABLE and a UPDATE:

```
ALTER TABLE Pluvometre ADD COLUMN geom geometry(point, 4326);
UPDATE Pluvometre SET geom = st_setsrid(st_makepoint(X, Y),4326);
```

Comment: Tahnk you for your help, I have another question, it's normal to have data like this: 0101000020AD10000012EE2D97018252C0378EA7BD4AB24640
              0101000020AD1000001EB1F208BF7C52C0E05EFA810EB34640 in my new geometry column ?

Comment: Yes, they are WKB strings, binary representation of Postgis geometries. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text#Well-known_binary. The functions St_SetSrid() and St_MakePoint() return this kind of data. Use the function St_AsText(geom) to see the original coordinates.